# GSM calling software on Windows 7 (Dell Mobile Broadband Card)

Tags: windows-7, mobile

I have a Dell Inspiron 1121 laptop with a Dell Mobile Broadband card, model 5620. The broadband manager included with the laptop allows GSM SMS, but not calling. I have a plan with unlimited data/talk/text.

Is there a software utility that would enable me to make and accept SIM calls (not VOIP)?

Before you post an answer, I realize there is a question as to wether or not the 5620 is capable of SIM calling, but for the purpose of this question, let us assume it does, and focus on possible software recommendations. Thank you.